# www htaccess redirect with segment in url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Where my site is hosted, I'm using .htaccess and it has a condition to remove the www and direct to the main page without the www.

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

Header set X-Frame-Options DENY

RewriteEngine On

# Required to allow direct-linking of pages so they can be processed by Angular
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://meusite.com.br [R=301,L]

</ifModule>
```

The problem is this, when someone accesses an internal page with www, it falls for this check and is directed to the home, example:

If someone accesses the link: http://www.meusite.com.br/conteudo/94-vai-criar-um-site-to-your-employee-said-you-can-noble

It will direct to http://meusite.com under the condition.

What I need, is that it is directed to the following link: http://meusite.com/content/94-vai-create-a-site-to-your-employee-behavior-which-cannot-can- -fine only by removing the www from the link.

Does anyone know if this check is possible in .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soluction:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

.htaccess is not able to translate your titles from portugese to english.
You should do redirection to normal domain with full link, and then do internal redirection with your backend (i.e. php, ruby) to proper translated link.

Use following code before your redirection, so links with conteudo will be catched here and redirected properly using backreferences:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\..* [NC]
    RewriteRule ^\/conteudo\/(.*)$ http://menusite.com.br/content/$1 [R=301,L]
```